# Inferring type of generic implicit parameter from return type

Tags: scala, types, implicits, implicit-typing

Say I have a simple class like this

```
abstract class Foo {
  implicit val impInt: Int = 42
  def f[A]()(implicit a: A): A
  val f2: Int = f()
}
```

When declaring val `f2`, compiler is able to infer that the type of implicit parameter of function `f` is `Int` because that type is the same as the result type, and result type needs to match the type of value `f2`, which is `Int`.

However, throwing an `Ordering[A]` into the mix:

```
def f[A]()(implicit a: A, m: Ordering[A]): A
val f2: Int = f()
```

results in this compile error:

> Ambiguous implicit values:  both value StringCanBuildFrom in object Predef of type => scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[String,Char,String]  and method $conforms in object Predef of type [A]=> <:<[A,A]  match expected type A

If I add the type information when invoking `f()`, it compiles:

```
val f2: Int = f[Int]()
```

First I encountered the case with implicit ordering and I thought it has to do with Scala inferring left-to-right; I thought it's not able to match the return type first and *then* infer the (implicit) parameter type of `f`. But then I tried the case without implicit ordering and saw that it works - it inferred that `f` must be parameterized by `Int` because the return type has to be an `Int` (because `f2` is an `Int`).

Note that if we remove `implicit a: A` and leave only the Ordering implicit parameter, the error remains, but becomes

> Diverging implicit expansion for type Ordering[A] starting with method Tuple9 in object Ordering.

Again, adding type parameter so that it becomes `val f2: Int = f[Int]()` helps.

What's going on? Why can the compiler infer that parameter `A` must be an `Int`, but not that parameter `Ordering[A]` must be an `Ordering[Int]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be something wrong with the way ordering instances are generated, as the code below works. I'd report a bug.

```scala
case object types {
  implicit def buh[X]: List[X] = List()
}
abstract class Foo {

  import types._

  def f[A]()(implicit l: List[A]): A
  val f2: Int = f()
}
```