# Infer a return type of a method based on the type expected in call site?

Tags: scala

So, basically, what I want to do is:

```
object WithoutWrap {

  def f[T: ClassTag](x: String): T = {
    println("Class of T is really… " ++ implicitly[ClassTag[T]].toString)
    ??? : T
  }

  def y: Int = f("abc")
  def z: Int = f[Int]("abc")

}
```

In both cases I’d like the inferred `T` to be `Int`. Let’s run this:

```
scala> WithoutWrap.y
Class of T is really… Nothing
scala.NotImplementedError: an implementation is missing

scala> WithoutWrap.z
Class of T is really… Int
scala.NotImplementedError: an implementation is missing
```

Unfortunately it’s `Nothing` in the first case.

However, if we return the `T` wrapped in something,

```
object WithWrap {

  trait Wrap[T]

  def f[T: ClassTag](x: String): Wrap[T] = {
    println("Class of T is really… " ++ implicitly[ClassTag[T]].toString)
    ??? : Wrap[T]
  }

  def y: Wrap[Int] = f("abc")
  def z: Wrap[Int] = f[Int]("abc")

}
```

… the `T` is inferred correctly in both cases:

```
scala> WithWrap.y
Class of T is really… Int
scala.NotImplementedError: an implementation is missing

scala> WithWrap.z
Class of T is really… Int
scala.NotImplementedError: an implementation is missing
```

How to get `Int` in both cases without wrapping?

Comment: Yeah, inferring the type based on method's return type can be tricky. I'm having a similar [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36388954/inferring-type-of-generic-implicit-parameter-from-return-type), possibly with the same (or at least related) cause

Comment: Since `Wrap[T]` is invariant of type `T`, the only subtype of `Wrap[Int]` is `Wrap[Int]` itself!!! You can change `Wrap[T]` to `Wrap[+T]` to verified.

Comment: @Eastsun, oh… right… So… I guess… no way to do this? =(

Comment: And in the case of just `T` it takes the most specific subtype of `T`, which is `nothing`. Right?

Comment: I don't think it can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, overload resolution is sensitive to expected type:

```
scala> case class A(s: String) ; case class B(s: String)
defined class A
defined class B

scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

object X {
def f(s: String): A = A(s)
def f(s: String)(implicit d: DummyImplicit): B = B(s)
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined object X

scala> val x: A = X f "hi"
x: A = A(hi)

scala> val y: B = X f "hi"
y: B = B(hi)
```