# Is there a Implicit value conflicts in Ordering[A] in scala's source code?

Tags: scala

```
trait LowPriorityOrderingImplicits {

/** This would conflict with all the nice implicit Orderings
    *  available, but thanks to the magic of prioritized implicits
    *  via subclassing we can make `Ordered[A] => Ordering[A]` only
    *  turn up if nothing else works.  Since `Ordered[A]` extends
    *  `Comparable[A]` anyway, we can throw in some Java interop too.
    */

implicit def ordered[A <% Comparable[A]]: Ordering[A] = new Ordering[A] {
def compare(x: A, y: A): Int = x compareTo y
 }

  implicit def comparatorToOrdering[A](implicit cmp: Comparator[A]): Ordering[A] = new Ordering[A] {
    def compare(x: A, y: A) = cmp.compare(x, y)
  }

}
```

there, two implicit function( ordered[A] and comparatorToOrdering[A]) all return Ordering[A], it should conflict, but why dose it work there?

Comment: Look at their signatures: the first requires a `Comparable[A]` and the second requires a `Comparator[A]`. These are different implicit searches.

Comment: maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36388954/inferring-type-of-generic-implicit-parameter-from-return-type/40609565

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Only* if for some type `A` there exists an implicit converstion `A => Comparable[A]` *and* an implicit `Comparator[A]`. The only way for those implicits to result in something ambiguous is if their own implicit parameters both resolve. In this case it would fail:

```
class Foo

implicit val fooComp = new java.util.Comparator[Foo] { def compare(a: Foo, b: Foo): Int = 0 }

val fooComparable = new java.lang.Comparable[Foo] { def compareTo(foo: Foo): Int = 0 }

implicit def foo2Comp(foo: Foo): Comparable[Foo] = fooComparable

scala> implicitly[Ordering[Foo]]
<console>:16: error: ambiguous implicit values:
 both method ordered in trait LowPriorityOrderingImplicits of type [A](implicit evidence$1: A => Comparable[A])scala.math.Ordering[A]
 and method comparatorToOrdering in trait LowPriorityOrderingImplicits of type [A](implicit cmp: java.util.Comparator[A])scala.math.Ordering[A]
 match expected type Ordering[Foo]
       implicitly[Ordering[Foo]]
                 ^
```

So it is technically possible to get an ambiguous implicits error, but it should be exceedingly rare. If something is already `Comparable`, there is no need for it to have an implicit `Comparator`.