# Ambiguous implicit values when using a generic method with an implicit parameter

Tags: scala, scala-implicits

In the following code:

```
trait Foo[T] {
  def get: T
}
implicit object FooInt extends Foo[Int] {
  override def get = 0
}
implicit object FooString extends Foo[String] {
  override def get = "0"
}
def fooImplicitGetter[T](implicit ev: Foo[T]): T = ev.get

val x: Int = fooImplicitGetter // Does not compile; ambiguous implicit values error


implicit val int = 0
implicit val string = ""
def implicitGetter[T](implicit ev: T): T = ev

val y: Int = implicitGetter // Compiles just fine
```

In the assignment of `x`, why can't the compiler infer that the type of fooImplicitGetter is `Int`, and therefore it needs to use the `FooInt` instance, as it can in the assignment of `y`? Is there any way of helping it other than `fooImplicitGetter[Int]`, passing `FooInt` explicitly, etc.? This is under 2.11 if it matter.

EDIT: This appears to be the same issue mentioned here: [Inferring type of generic implicit parameter from return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36388954/inferring-type-of-generic-implicit-parameter-from-return-type), so I've modified my example to match. I'm also fine with closing it for duplication, unless someone has an answer.

Comment: Please add an actual implementation of `fooGetter` where the inference engine resolves `T`.

Comment: You could pass the implicit explicitly, but then what's the point? Is this what you're actually trying to achieve? I'm having hard time making sense of the example.

Comment: @jwvh: Why does the actual implementation matter? It's not as if replacing fooImplicitGetter's implementation with ??? works. The compiler doesn't look at the implementation.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I don't want to pass the implicit explicitly, obviously. I said as much in the text. I want the compiler to infer that the correct type for fooImplicitGetter is Int.